# sharing only select rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a sheet with data compiled via application forms which are filled out by many people.  I want to be able to edit that information and share portions of it with the people who fill out the application forms - but have each person see **only their information**

For example, in the list below, I'd like to 'share' with Dana only **her** line from within my sheet and not allow her see the other data.  Is this possible?

SAMPLE:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right now, it is not possible. There are many forum threads pertaining to the same question but none seem to give a solution to the problem. I imagine that there is a way to have a script display the info to Dana using 3280 (or anything unique to her data) as an id/password for instance.
Otherwise, giving access to Dana is equivalent to giving Dana access view to all other rows as well.

Comment: True, right now the only option is to create separate file for each user and import data they need to see from master file and import their input into it.